# https Apache2 Webserver Not Working (Self-Signed Certificate)

Tags: apache, http, https, webserver

I am using a Raspberry PI to host my apache2 webserver.

I have apache2 installed and have been able to serve the webserver both on my in house router and also online with a domain name using an unencrypted http web address. My port forwarding for my router/service is enabled for the Raspberry PI for both port 80 and port 443.

I have gone through as many of the recommended stackoverflow questions about setting up a self-signed https certificate on the apache2 webserver as well as reading through multiple (5+) different articles online, and trying all of them separately to try and get my web server working (including the wiki page below which is similar to most of the articles online).

When I run my ip address http://IP_ADDRESS I am able to access my server that is in the /var/www/html folder as expected. However, when trying to follow the steps in the wiki page (among other pages) to generate a private key as well as link my conf file to the key, I get an
"Unable to connect" error in the browser. When going back to http (non encrypted) it works fine. I put my cert file below for reference.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName {Server_Name}.com #{Server_Name} has the server name
    ServerAlias www.{Server_Name}.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile        /etc/ssl/localcerts/apache.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile     /etc/ssl/localcerts/apache.key

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName {Server_Name}.com #{Server_Name} has the server name

    Redirect / https://www.{Server_Name}.com/        
</VirtualHost>
```

Has anyone been successful in getting a RasPI to host a https server, and if so is there anything in particular that needs to be done differently than using a normal Debian based machine?

https://wiki.debian.org/Self-Signed_Certificate

Answer (score 0):

This has been a pain for me, trying to figure out what everyone is forgetting to mention..

First, chmod to 600, so it can't be downloaded.
Second, filenames are case-sensitive (this keeps getting me)
Third, make sure the SSL file is enabled

if I ever get any farther, I'll post it here so I can remember..